# ubuntu php pdo_sqlsev install fall but sqlsrv is successful

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-16.04, sqlsrv, php-7.2

Does anyone successfully install pdo_sqlsrv in ubuntu php 7.2.9 environment? I only see sqlsrv on phpinfo(), pdo_sqlsrv always installed fail. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found an afternoon and finally found a solution.
The file 30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini in /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d ,
copy to /etc/php/7.2/apache2 , it work !!

Answer (score 0):

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools

sudo apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev

sudo apt-get -y install gcc g++ make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config

sudo apt-get install php-pear php7.2-dev

sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv

printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini

printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini

phpenmod -v 7.2 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

a2enmod mpm_prefork

a2enmod php7.2

service apache2 restart